# Using Oracle SQL, how can I concatenate data from multiple rows into one row without using PIVOT, LISTAGG or custom built functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, listagg

I'm using Oracle SQL. This is the table:

| doc-nr | code | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0000010 | 155 | Sample text from code 155 |
| 0000010 | 455 | Sample text1 from code 455 |
| 0000010 | 455 | Sample text2 from code 455 |
| 0000010 | 455 | Sample text3 from code 455 |

With this query:

```
SELECT t155.text as "155", t455.text as "455" 
FROM myTable t155
JOIN myTable t455 ON t155.doc-nr = t455.doc-nr
WHERE t155.code = '155'
AND t455.code = '455'
```

I get ugly result:

| 155 | 455 |
| --- | --- |
| Sample text from code 155 | Sample text1 from code 455 |
| Sample text from code 155 | Sample text2 from code 455 |
| Sample text from code 155 | Sample text3 from code 455 |

I want the output to be one row:

| 155 | 455 | 455 | 455 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sample text from code 155 | Sample text1 from code 455 | Sample text2 from code 455 | Sample text3 from code 455 |

Or:

| 155 | 455 |
| --- | --- |
| Sample text from code 155 | Sample text1 from code 455; Sample text2 from code 455; Sample text3 from code 455 |

How can you do this with Oracle SQL without using PIVOT or LISTAGG or using custom built functions?

Comment: Why don't you want to use pivot or listagg; and what other restrictions are you imposing, and why?

Comment: If I use listagg, I can't seem to export results (ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long). To solve this error I guess I should write custom function which I'm not allowed to use (Oracle user restriction thing), so the function is off. Pivot is something I'm not quite familiar with in SQL at this point, so I was wondering is there another solution people use to get this thing from above done?

Answer (score 2):

You can create such a function returning `SYS_REFCURSOR` in order to pivot your data dynamically

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Cols RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols1     VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols2     VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( ''''||rn||''' AS "'||rn||'"' , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY text ),
         LISTAGG( 'MAX("'||rn||'") AS "'||rn||'"' , ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY text )
    INTO v_cols1, v_cols2
    FROM 
    ( SELECT code||'_'||ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_nr, code ORDER BY text) AS rn, t.*
        FROM tab t );

  v_sql :='SELECT '||v_cols2||
          '  FROM
             (
              SELECT code||''_''||ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_nr, code ORDER BY text) AS rn, t.*
                FROM tab t 
             )
            PIVOT
            (
             MAX(text) FOR rn IN ( '|| v_cols1 ||' )
            )
            GROUP BY doc_nr';            

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
```

which will generate this output as a SQL statement

```
SELECT MAX("155_1") AS "155_1", 
       MAX("455_1") AS "455_1", 
       MAX("455_2") AS "455_2", 
       MAX("455_3") AS "455_3"
  FROM
  (
   SELECT code||'_'||ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY doc_nr, code ORDER BY text) AS rn, 
          t.*
     FROM tab t 
  )
  PIVOT
  (
   MAX(text) FOR rn IN ( '155_1' AS "155_1", '455_1' AS "455_1", '455_2' AS "455_2", 
                         '455_3' AS "455_3" )
  )
  GROUP BY doc_nr;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=90c70dfe24aee91f4fc8cad48cd61358)</kbd>

and then run this code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Pivoted_Cols;
PRINT rc
```

from *SQL Developer's Command Line* in order to see the result set.

Comment: This is great but the frustrating thing is that my company is not allowed to write custom functions for whatsoever reason. I'll try to make something out of pivot function though.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the size, you can use XML aggregation:

```sql
select mt.doc_nr, mt.text as text_155,
  xmlquery('
    for $i in .
      return <e>{ fn:string-join($i/text, "; ") }</e>/text()'
    passing tmp.xml
    returning content
  ).getclobval() as text_455
from mytable mt
join (
  select doc_nr, xmlagg(xmlelement("text", text)) as xml
  from mytable
  where code = 455
  group by doc_nr
) tmp
on tmp.doc_nr = mt.doc_nr
where mt.code = 155
```

```
DOC_NR  | TEXT_155                  | TEXT_455                                                                          
:------ | :------------------------ | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000010 | Sample text from code 155 | Sample text1 from code 455; Sample text3 from code 455; Sample text2 from code 455
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a55ba16820b138133cefbf787a20634) including the intermediate steps.

Comment: Should it be suitable for version 11.2.0.4? This one is quite old now.

Comment: @Ivan_M2 - [Yes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a55ba16820b138133cefbf787a20634) - db<>fiddle lets you try it in 18c or 11gR2.

Comment: Still having issue exporting results. Somehow I get blob or clob columns which I can't export. But thanks anyway for this alternative which I wasn't aware of before.

Comment: Yes, I included `getclobval()` so you get a CLOB result; you can't get a varchar2 result because you'll hit the same 4000 character limit behind the ORA-01489. You should maybe ask a new question about your export mechanism and the problem that has with CLOBs. The dynamic pivot option Barbaros showed might work for you, but is whatever is going to consume this able to cope with a variable number of columns in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Using xml functions in a such way is not good for performance (when there is more data) but in this case it works fine:

```
SELECT t155.text  as "155",
       sys_xmlagg(xmlelement(col, t455.text || ',')).extract('/ROWSET/COL/text()')
                 .getclobval() as "455"
  FROM myTable t155
  JOIN myTable t455
    ON t155."doc-nr" = t455."doc-nr"
 WHERE t155.code = '155'
   AND t455.code = '455'
 GROUP BY t155.text
```